# Why does this Calculus II sequence diverge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, divergent-series

What steps should I take to understand why this sequence diverges (specifically, not to +∞ or -∞)?

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{8(n!)}{(-2)^n}$$

Comment: Try the ratio test.

Comment: moral of the story is that $n!$ get's big really fast. In fact $\frac{x^n}{n!}$ tends to zero for any x.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Because the terms of the sequence alternate in sign, the sequence can converge if and only if it converges to zero.

And the magnitude of the $n^{\textrm{th}}$ term is $$8\cdot\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{2}{2}\cdot \frac{3}{2}\cdots\frac{n}{2}$$
Note that all factors beyond the third are larger than $1$, so do you see why the terms can't converge to zero?

Answer (score 2):

1. Show that the absolute values diverges to $+\infty$. (*Hint:* $n! > 2\cdot 3^{n-2}$ for $n \geq 3$.)
2. Show that the series alternates, i.e. $a_{2n} > 0$ while $a_{2n+1} < 0$.
3. Conclude that the series does not converges (from 1.), and does not diverge to $+\infty$ nor to $-\infty$ (from 2.).

Comment: From your answer, I gather the following facts:

1. If the absolute value of a sequence diverges, then the sequence diverges (but we do not necessarily know the direction of its divergence).

2. If an alternating sequence diverges, then it doesn't diverge to an infinity.

Am I correct? Thanks.

Comment: Take the contrapositive: if a sequence converges, then its absolute value converges.  Here, the absolute values do not converge, so...

Comment: For the second part: if a sequence diverges to infinity, say +infty, then by definition there is N such that a_n > 1 for all n> N. But here, the sequence stays negative half the times...

Answer (score 0):

$n!$ "grows" faster then $2^n$. so the $$\frac{8(n!)}{(-2)^n}$$ approaches $\infty$ faster then it approaches zero. as $n\rightarrow\infty$
also $(-2)^n$ oscillates between positive and negative values.